# randomly Select XML nodes with same names

Tags: c#, xml, random

I have this XML file:

```
<Main>
<QA>
    <question>What is your favorite color?</question>
    <!--pick random!-->
    <answer>Blue</answer>
    <answer>Red</answer>
    <answer>Green</answer>
    <answer>Yellow</answer>
</QA>

<QA>
    <question>What is your favorite programming language?</question>
    <!--pick random!-->
    <answer>PHP</answer>
    <answer>C#</answer>
    <answer>Java</answer>
    <answer>VB.Net</answer>
</QA>
```

I want when the user enter one of the question that specified in above xml file, program pick a random answer from  nodes.
For example when user enters "What is your favorite programming language?" in TextBox,
program must generate PHP,C#,Java or VB.Net randomly.

this is my code but not correct:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("QA.xml");

XmlNodeList xList = xml.SelectNodes("Main/QA");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xList)
{
    string Question = xn["question"].InnerText;
    if (Question == txtQuestion.Text)
    {
        XmlNodeList answerlist = xml.SelectNodes("Main/QA/answer");
        foreach (XmlNode ans in answerlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ans.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

Blue
Red
Green
Yellow
PHP
C#
Java
VB.Net

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("QA.xml");

XmlNodeList xList = xml.SelectNodes("Main/QA");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xList)
{
    string Question = xn["question"].InnerText;
    if (Question == txtQuestion.Text)
    {
        XmlNodeList answerlist = xn.SelectNodes("./answer");
        foreach (XmlNode ans in answerlist
            .Cast<XmlNode>()
            .OrderBy(elem => Guid.NewGuid()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ans.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using Linq To Xml,

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("QA.xml");

var question = xDoc.Descendants("QA")
                   .First(d => d.Element("question").Value == txtQ.Text);

var answer = question.Elements()
                     .Skip(rnd.Next(0, question.Elements().Count()))
                     .First().Value;
```

Comment: it's OK, but have a bug!  when i enter the question program generate both answer and question in output!

Comment: @IRonMAN Just for future readers. It doesn't have a bug. I tested it again and got the correct output. It must be somewhere within *your code* (My guess you try to print `question` which is node `QA` and is parent of `<answers>`s )